# How can I create a top priority firewall rule for a trusted mac address?

Tags: iptables, centos7, mac-address, firewall-cmd

I want to accept all packets sent to my centos7 VPS from my device regardless of options defined on public zone. (**I want to remove ssh service from public zone and just be able to connect from my mac address!**)

But when I add my mac address as a source to Trusted zone, if I remove ssh service from public I'll not be able to connect to vps via ssh until I add ssh service to public zone which is accessible for public. I tried rich rules for getting higher priority but got same results. If I add Ip address as source it works ok but my ip address is not static and what I want is enabling this option for my mac address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC addresses are only relevant on a local subnet - your VPS can't see your remote devices MAC address. In short, you can't achieve what you're trying tobdo.

Comment: Thats too disappointing :(